# Simple install on Asus X205TA (over known good / patched Ubuntu?)

Tags: system-installation, asus

I ordered an Asus X205TA because it's known to have good support for Ubuntu. Someone made an ISO and lists the instructions, including some patches for basic functionality:

https://github.com/lopaka/instructions/blob/master/ubuntu-16.04-install-asus-x205ta.md

I know Elementary is based on Ununtu. I assume I should install Ubuntu with the ISO /  patches then install Elementary. If that's right, what's the best way to do this so whatever patches from the original install remain in place? If that's wrong what should I do differently?

I don't care about audio (apparently an issue that needed patching with Ubuntu). Wi-Fi and suspend (or hibernate) are my main requirements. Support for one of the two sleep modes is absolutely critical. It's useless otherwise.

Beyond that, this machine will be a glorified typewriter. With that in mind I want to set it up, back the drive up, and easily restore it on the same or a different machine (if mine gets flaky or is stolen.) I don't want to have to maintain it, it's a writing appliance that should just work.

I don't want Windows so dual boot or anything remotely in support of Windows is totally unnecessary.

I'm a pretty hardcore nerd but haven't used Linux for much of anything. I can hold my own in macOS terminal for basic things but just pretend (and deride me for being) a n00b. I can take it. :)

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

Firstly let's clear your misconception about eOS. elementary is only based on ubuntu. It's not a program that can be run on ubuntu. Ubuntu and elementary are two different OS.

In layman's term, you are first installing Windows and then MacOS on it so you can use Windows' ram management.

Hope that clears it.

You can do this:

Get an ISO image of elementary from https://elementary.io/ 
You may want to try it before installing. Since elementary is based on ubuntu which uses Linux kernel 4.8.x, you may run into problems.

Either you can try Googling for workarounds or ask answers to those problems on this forum, or you can install another distro with an upgraded kernel. I suggest openSUSE Tumbleweed which uses kernel 4.10.

Comment: I totally get that it's a different OS but it's derived from the Ubuntu core stuff. I guess maybe my question was wrong. Can I take a working Ununtu machine with all the necessary drivers and install Elementary so I get the benefit of the drivers of a known good Ubuntu setup, then run another installer to replace the crummy Ubuntu pieces with the shiny simplicity of Elementary.

Comment: No that's not possible. But since elementary and ubuntu are share a lot of dependencies, you can try following those instructions on an elementary OS ISO.